# How do I configure Dependency Injection in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, twig, zend-framework2

DISCLAIMER: I'm a complete noob to Zend.

I'm evaluating **Zend Framework 2** at work, and trying to configure it to work with **ZfTwig** for templating.  (See here: https://github.com/mtymek/ZfTwig)

I got through `Step 3` of the config ok, but I can't figure out `Step 4`.

I tried placing the following in `application.config`, but no good.

Where am I supposed to put this?

```
return array(
    'di' => array(
        'instance' => array(
            // setup other stuff...
            // ...

            // setup view script resolvers - very similar to configuration
            // from ZendSkeletonApplication
            'Zend\View\Resolver\AggregateResolver' => array(
                'injections' => array(
                    'Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver',
                    'ZfTwig\TemplatePathStack',
                ),
            ),
            'Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'map'  => array(
                        'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.twig',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'ZfTwig\TemplatePathStack' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'paths'  => array(
                        'application' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // Tell TwigRenderer how it should locate .twig files
            'ZfTwig\TwigRenderer' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'resolver' => 'Zend\View\Resolver\AggregateResolver',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Google is no help... I can't find any documentation on Zend's site or anywhere telling me where this is supposed to go.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The Twig Module you've linked is outdated. See ZfCommons repository for a newer and easier implementation ;) https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcTwig

Comment: @Sam, thanks for the direction on ZfcTwig!  That's exactly what I need.  Just out of curiosity, do you know where that di config above would go, though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `di` configuration is from the first betas of Zend Framework 2. `Zend\Di` is a component still available, but internally (as with many other modules) replaced by `Zend\ServiceManager`.

Basically, both are able to provide dependency injection. Only for `Zend\Di` it can do this kind-of automatically and for `Zend\ServiceManager` there are other options to make dependency injection more explicit.

To give an answer to your question: ZfcTwig is now part of ZF-Commons and https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcTwig is the location you have to search for now. Just for your insights, [this file](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcTwig/blob/master/src/ZfcTwig/Service/ViewTwigRendererFactory.php) is an example of a factory used by the service manager. For more background of service managers in Zend Framework 2, [I have written a blog post](http://juriansluiman.nl/en/article/120/using-zend-framework-service-managers-in-your-application) two months ago which might be interesting.

Comment: Thanks, Jurian.  Lots of useful info there.